# Why is this Scala for loop translation not equivalent?

Tags: scala, for-loop

I tried writing this code

```
val req: mutable.Buffer[InterfaceHttpData] = /*...*/
for (attr: Attribute <- req) {
  println(attr.getValue())
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.Attribute => Unit
 required: io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.InterfaceHttpData => ?
```

I've read through [the specs](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops) and as far as I can tell, this for loop should be equivalent to the following.

```
req.withFilter { case attr: Attribute => true; case _ => false }.foreach {
  case attr: Attribute => println(attr.getValue())
}
```

This compiles cleanly. Am I misunderstanding how the for loop transformation is done?

Answer (score 0):

According to the spec, this transformation only applies if `p` in `p <- e` is irrefutable for the type of `e`, which in your example means `(p: U) <- (e: F[T])` where `T <: U`.

```
scala> trait T
defined trait T

scala> class C extends T
defined class C

scala> val c: List[C] = Nil
c: List[C] = List()

scala> for (e: T <- c) println(e)

scala> val t: List[T] = Nil
t: List[T] = List()

scala> for (e: C <- t) println(e)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : C => Unit
 required: T => ?
       for (e: C <- l) println(e)
                 ^
```

Comment: Where are you reading this? As far as I can tell, irrefutability of the pattern only affects whether `withFilter` call is present or not. Either way, I still don't understand why there is a type mismatch in your last expression; since `e: C` is not irrefutable for the type of `t` the translation should be `t.withFilter {case e: C => true; case _ => false}.foreach { case e: C => println(e) }`, shouldn't it?

Comment: https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/08-pattern-matching.html#patterns, Irrefutable Patterns

Comment: But you're right, it should still translate (read it too fast), maybe that's a but in the compiler/spec then...

Comment: No I meant where you read that the transformation only applies for irrefutable patterns, but from the follow up comment I assume you figured that out already :)

Comment: Yes, it's a compiler bug, see the answer to the duplicated question. Funnily enough, comment there read the same part of specs too fast too...